# Create a Map.Entry instance in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, syntax

What is the most idiomatic way to create a `Map.Entry` instance in  Groovy? Two approaches I've come up so far rely on JDK types/methods:

```
def entry = ['foo', 'bar'] as AbstractMap.SimpleEntry
def entry = [foo: 'bar'].entrySet()[0]
```

Is there a Groovier way using Groovy-specific syntax or GDK methods?

Comment: What is it that you want to do with the `Map.Entry` once you create it?  The answer to that will affect what the best way to create it (or have it created by the `Map` itself) is.

Comment: Why not just `def entry = Map.entry('foo', 'bar')`? [Map.entry](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)), q.v.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I have a Spock test for a static method that takes a Map.Entry instance and returns a boolean. I'm trying to craft a readable "expect:" block so I can list different keys, values, and expected return values in a table format

Comment: @DavidConrad I like that--I wasn't aware of that Java 11 method

Answer (score 1):

In Java 9 a convenience method was added to Map for creating entries: [`Map.entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)):

```
def entry = Map.entry('foo', 'bar')
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, I use `Pair.of` for lightweight entry instances:

```
@Grab('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11')
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair

def map = ['foo','bar','baz'].collectEntries {
  Pair.of(it, it.length())
}
```